# how to add data labels on top of all bars in searborn barplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

My data is like below:

```
data=io.StringIO("""x1,x2,x3
    1,A,0.42
    1,B,0.62
    2,A,0.24
    2,B,0.58
    """)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",")
```

I was trying to make a seaborn barplot with data label above each bar:

```
ax = sns.barplot (data=df, x='x2', y='x3', hue='x1', 
                  palette=sns.xkcd_palette(['blue', 'red']))
ax.legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.03, 0.9),
          ncol=1, fancybox=True, shadow=True)

barwidth = [0.4,0.4]
ax.set_ylim(0, 0.7)
label_ = df.x3
for bar,newwidth, label in zip(ax.patches,barwidth, label_):
    x = bar.get_x()
    width = bar.get_width()
    height = bar.get_height()

    centre = x+width/2.
    bar.set_x(centre-newwidth/2.)
    bar.set_width(newwidth)

    ax.text(x+width/2.,
            height + 0.03,
            '{0:4.2f}'.format(label),
            ha="center")
```

However, this is what I got. It seems like seaborn treats the bars as two patches instead of 4, one for each group. I cannot figure out a way to solve the issue. Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just made a minor mistake in defining `barwidth`. Its length should be four:

```
barwidth = [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4]
```

As you have it now, your for loop is only going through two iterations because it limited by the length of barwidth.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Michael